# Issues Booting Up Ubuntu After Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade

I am having issues after doing an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. During the upgrading process, there are some errors.

After rebooting the OS, the system starts up with errors:

[TIME] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by.....
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /.....
[TIME] Timed out waiting for device debv-mapper-ubuntu/.....
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1.

I did a SSH into the OS and found that although the OS is now 20.04, the kernel is still the old version (4.15.0-219-generic) and I cannot use the apt command now (error: apt: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory).

**Output of sudo blkid**

> /dev/sda1: UUID="e1f0a45f-de7e-4991-ba88-1e2ba0a0c7bd" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="d32eb318-01" 
> /dev/sda5: UUID="kfEwtS-k1Ro-frcF-jCGK-pcsU-fTI1-ybGwY4" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="d32eb318-05"
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="abd36f2b-29b7-4d3a-a22a-d187895b2b82" TYPE="ext4" 
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="f857b46f-3ffc-4cd5-8b92-2888ad443337" TYPE="swap"

**Output of cat /etc/fstab**

> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1 
> #/boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
> UUID=e1f0a45f-de7e-4991-ba88-1e2ba0a0c7bd /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2 
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
> /dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

I appreciate any advice to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Providing details as to what the errors were (*not just telling us there were some errors*) would allow us to better understand. What you've provided would make me want to boot *live* media & perform file-system checks first; have you?

Comment: Consider fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04. It will be supported until 2027

Comment: @guiverc

The booting up message is

[TIME] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by....
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot. 
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /..... 
[TIME] Timed out waiting for device debv-mapper-ubuntu/..... 
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1.

Comment: Did you boot *live* media and see what is available; what is not available (*either due to hardware problems, or just logical problems that will be detected & auto-fixed if `fsck` or whatever command appropriate for your unstated file-systems is run*). The detail you want to check is the detail in that device dev-disk-by detail that you've listed only as "..." during the *live* session.  I'd also explore the messages you didn't provide whilst in that *live* session if all file-system errors are fixed.